# urllib.request.urlopen() URLError

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I tried to open http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

```
## all imports
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
import urllib.request, urllib.error
import bs4 #this is beautiful soup
import time
import operator
import socket
import pickle
import re # regular expressions

from pandas import Series
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context("talk")
sns.set_style("white")

from secret import *    
url = 'http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
print(source)
```

But it returned a Error, I have searched around but couldn't find any solution. It worked for other sites.

```
SSLEOFError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1253             try:
-> 1254                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
   1255             except OSError as err: # timeout error

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1254                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
   1255             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1256                 raise URLError(err)
   1257             r = h.getresponse()
   1258         except:

URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the site http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ redirects to https using SSL upon visit explains why there's something wrong with SSL. The [`SSLEOFError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLEOFError) means that there has been an abrupt termination of the underlying SSL connection. Due to the fact that it is indeed working fine for me, are you sure that your network is working as intended? You might be sitting behind some kind of proxy which gives you problems with SSL or does not allow SSL connections (e.g. due to a missing root certificate allowing the proxy to intercept the connections).

You could as well try to ignore certificates by adding a custom SSL context (Python >= 2.7.9/3.4.3):

```
import ssl

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

urllib.requests.urlopen("https://the.url/path", context=context).read() # ...
```

However, I'm not sure if that solves your problem because the error might occur even before certificates are checked (e.g. in a case where a potential proxy just aborts SSL connections).

Side note/Recommendation: There is also a nice other Python module called [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) which makes HTTP requests even more simpler.

Comment: I tried your way it came up with another error   `gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1253             try:
-> 1254                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>`

Comment: To me it seems that there is something "wrong" with your underlying system. Are you sure that you're not behind some kind of proxy and your OS is working fine network-related? Someone else might have another suggestion. (I tested both your and my solution on the URL you gave in your question and it worked fine both times.)

Comment: Sorry, it just came up with the same SSLError. I will try another way such as `requests`. Thanks.

Comment: With `requests` you can try something like this: `content = requests.get("https://url", verify=False).text` to get the HTML source of this URL. The `verify=False` disables SSL certificate validation. If you're getting somewhat the same error, you definitely know that there's something else wrong with your underlying system.

Comment: Yes, I got the same error. Maybe it is because my system, I will try it another time. But I don't get it why it stills worked with other sites.

Comment: I have fixed it with Anaconda Jupyter. Maybe some package is missing when I ran Jupyter Notebook from terminal.

Comment: You didn't mention using an enviroment like that. At least you got it working for now! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not Mobile verified user, down after environment on the right pane, click to verify your mobile, then there it will be internet option appear, toggle it to on. Then run the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).